# Conditional parameter passing with MooseX::Params::Validate

Tags: perl, moose

I work alot with `Moose` packages in Perl that use `MooseX::Params::Validate` to define an interface. These interfaces tend to be rather flexible and allow for multiple optional parameters. Unfortunately this is Perl so the return types will vary based on the optional parameters and there is a benefit to passing the optional parameters in most cases when defined in the caller. Various methods exported from `MooseX::Params::Validate` are used in this codebase so due to the various ways that package will be handled `undef` parameters I can not passing it will be graceful in anyway. I tend to use the following method, but it comes up a lot in reviews, and I would like to ask if there is another way to achieve this flexibility.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $bar;

Foo->foo({
    foo => 'I, Foo need a VERY flexible interface. ',
    $bar ? ( bar => $bar ) : ()
});

$bar = "Very flexible...";

Foo->foo({
    foo => 'I, Foo need a VERY flexible interface. ',
    $bar ? ( bar => $bar ) : ()
});

package Foo;

use Moose;
use MooseX::Params::Validate;

sub foo {
    my $self = shift;
    my ( $foo, $bar ) = validated_list(
      \@_,
      foo => { isa => 'Str' },
      bar => { isa => 'Str', optional => 1 },
    );

    print $foo . $bar . "\n";
}

1;
```

The ternary operator to check the variables `defined` state is what always leaves me wanting a `//` type parameter option, but I can't see anywhere this type of operation is supported.

Answers for the `caller` is preferred as I don't want to (won't) change the interface of the various packages, but I am open to answers showing methods of handling `undef` parameters values being passed as well.

Comment: For caller, your "idiom" seems laborous [and, more importantly, error prone]. How about replacing the ternary with a more straightforward helper function like: `sub defme { my(@arr);  push(@arr,$_[0],$_[1]) if ($_[1]);  @arr; }`? Then, you have `defme("bar",$bar)` instead of the ternary. Or, in constructor, do the `//` or `//=` as needed _before_ calling `validated_list` since the first arg always points to a temp anyway?

Comment: @CraigEstey can you explain how it is more error prone and laborious (I was mainly concerned with the readiblity), and how your solution works because I am not seeing how it is applicable ?

Comment: My function, AFAICT, does what the ternary does--produces an array that is either filled with `($sym,$val)` or empty. And, IMO, `defme("bar",$bar)` is more readable than the [longer] `$bar ? (bar => $bar) : ()`. The fnc call is shorter and simpler than the ternary syntax. And, if needed, you can add debug printfs to the fnc. But, it is probably better to have all callers just do `(bar => $var)` and let `foo` deal with it rather than put the responsibility on the callers. Even if you still want the ternary, `foo` still needs to defensively check this anyway. So, if check why not fix as well?

Comment: It looks like `foo` breaks if it gets `bar => $bar` if `$bar` is undef. But, as I said, having every caller do the check (via ternary)? I'd just pass the whatever and have `foo` strip the undef values from the hash: `@sym = keys(%$hash); for $sym (@sym) { delete{$hash->{$sym}} unless (defined($hash->{$sym})); }`

Answer (score 0):

As [Craig Estey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5382650/craig-estey) said in his comment, I think it would make sense just to pass in the options to your function and not having to care whether they are undefined or not. Instead, strip undefined hash keys as a preprocessing step before calling `MooseX::Params::Validate::validated_list()`. For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $bar;

Foo->foo({
    foo => 'I, Foo need a VERY flexible interface. ',
    bar => $bar
});

package Foo;

use Moose;
use MooseX::Params::Validate ();

sub foo {
    my $self = shift;

    my ( $foo, $bar ) = validated_list(
      \@_,
      foo => { isa => 'Str' },
      bar => { isa => 'Str', optional => 1 },
    );

    $bar //= 'undef';  # Just to avoid printing warning: Use of uninitialized value 
    print $foo . $bar . "\n";
}

sub validated_list {
    for (keys %{ $_[0]->[0] } ) {
        delete $_[0]->[0]{$_} if !defined $_[0]->[0]{$_};
    }
    return MooseX::Params::Validate::validated_list( @_ );
}
1;
```

Comment: The Moose packages are a black box for my question

Comment: @MattSizzle I am not sure what you mean by `black box`. To me,  a `black box` would mean that you cannot modify anything inside. You can only communicate through the API. Could you explain what you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

The `Maybe` type might be what you are looking for. Normally MooseX::Params::Validate does *not* allow undef to be passed for things liked Str, forcing you to use a ternary to conditionally pass or not pass it. An optional variable will be undef anyways in the subroutine, but with Maybe it makes it easier for the caller to just pass through the variables they have (which may or not be defined).

```
sub foo {
    my $self = shift;
    my ( $foo, $bar ) = validated_list(
      \@_,
      foo => { isa => 'Str' },
      bar => { isa => 'Maybe[Str]', optional => 1 }
    );

    print $foo . $bar . "\n";
}
```

By using Maybe[Str], it will now accept the undef value and you can handle this undef how you see fit in your subroutine.

```
Maybe[`a] accepts either `a or undef.
```

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose-2.0604/lib/Moose/Manual/Types.pod